# Is there a way to use something like RewriteRule ... [PT] for an external URL?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a non-apache web server running on port 8000, but this cannot be accessed from behind corporate firewalls. So, I would like to use my apache 2 server as a proxy to this other web server. I've tried using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /.* http://buildbot.synergy-foss.org:8000/builders/ [PT]
```

... but this does not work; I get:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this
>   server could not understand.

However, it worked fine with `[R]`.

#### Update:

Also, when using `ProxyPass`, I get this error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /
>   on this server.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend using `mod_rewrite` for proxying unless you have a reason; `mod_rewrite` may be more powerful, but it sounds like you wouldn't need it..  For example, it sounds like you just want the following:

```
# Does't disable ProxyPass; but will disable everything you're not using
ProxyPass off
# Always setup a reverse proxy so that Apache can rewrite the URL
ProxyPass / http://buildbot.synergy-foss.org:8000/builders/
ProxyPassReverse / http://buildbot.synergy-foss.org:8000/builders/
```

Make sure you enable mod_proxy ([documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)) as well.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You want the `[P]` flag, not `[PT]`.  `[PT]` on a rewrite rule says 'pass through', allow processing by other handlers (`Alias`, `Redirect` etc).

You could also achieve the same results with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), starting with something like:

```
ProxyPass / http://buildbot.synergy-foss.org:8000/builders/
```

Comment: If I use [P] I get the error: `You don't have permission to access / on this server.` and using ProxyPass gives a slightly different error. Are you absolutely sure both of those work?

Comment: By default, proxying is disallowed.  Look at Basic Examples/Reverse Proxying in that linked URL to fix.

Comment: Hmm, ok, now I'm getting: `[error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(0) failed in child 29869 for worker proxy:forward`

Comment: Have you restarted Apache, as opposed to just reloading config?